# Wordpress - Get post id for custom post in functions.php

Tags: wordpress

I need to get the id for a custom post in `functions.php`.

I tried the following but none are working:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID ()

global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;

global $wp_query;
$post_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
```

What I'm doing is sending data with jquery to a functions and I need the id here:

```
if ( isset( $_POST["tab_id"] ) ) {

$url = explode('?', 'http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] .     $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$ID = url_to_postid($url[0]);

var_dump($ID);
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
$project_id = $_POST['post_id'];
var_dump( $project_id );
$tab_id = $_POST['tab_id'];

//form processing code here

}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to get it? Is it within certain hook? Certain page?

Comment: I added more details. Hope it helps.

Comment: More here: http://pastebin.com/LXnvkv3N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get it at ajax handler function. At that time, none of these function will work be it built in post type or custom post type. Easiest solution would be to pass ID along with your ajax request.

Another solution is to use `url_to_postid` with `wp_get_referer`. You can check docs for these functions [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid) and [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer). I wouldn't recommend this one though.

Comment: Yeah. This is how it needs to be done. I was complicating things. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no post data available at this point. If you have to get the post Id here, you could try extracting it from the url:

```
$url = explode('?', 'http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$ID = url_to_postid($url[0]);
```

Comment: It's giving me `int(0)`. I'll edit my question to give a few more details.